# How is it possible for the contents of a single folder on an external harddisk to become corrupt?

Tags: windows-xp, external-hard-drive

I have a Seagate External hard drive. We use this to store images (.img) of machine states. Windows embedded XP is the OS of the machine these images originate from AND the OS of the station we use to load sais image onto a CF card. The images inside one folder of the Seagate (which we have made many copies of using this same process in the past) suddenly stopped being transferable! That is, when we use SelfImage software to put an image in this folder on the Seagate to a CF card, then when I go to open the CF card to see the system image was loaded correctly, I get the pop-up "Drive is not Formatted. Format now?".

Other images not in this folder are still recoverable under this same process. We have tried replacing all the hardware and even reloaded the XP Embedded OS.

I am fairly certain the problem is with the images inside the folder itself.

How is this possible? How would a single folder become corrupt. An entire partition I could see happening, but this is so specific.

Also, are there any hopes of recovering the images in this folder?